# Getting error 409 when fetching data from html form

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I'm encountering the following problem: I have an HTML file that uses a form to receive the data for a user's registry in the system. I get these values ​​through my JavaScript and do a fetch for the API that does the registration and unrolls all the rest of the cadastral process. But when I'm doing the registration I run into error 409 and can not find the reason for this error in my code. Can you still find / solve?

## REGISTER FORM

```
    <form id="register" name="register" onsubmit="submitRegister(); return false;">
        <h4>Cadastre-se</h4>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Primeiro Nome" id="register-fName" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Último Nome" id="register-lName" required>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="register-email" required>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" id="register-psw" required>
                <button type="submit">Cadastrar-se</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

## JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION

```
    function submitRegister() {
        var fName = document.getElementById("register-fName").value  
        var lname = document.getElementById("register-lName").value  
        var email = document.getElementById("register-email").value  
        var senha = document.getElementById("register-psw").value

        var data = {
            email: email,
            senha: senha,
            primeiroNome: fName,
            ultimoNome: lname

        } 

        fetch('https://api-ucdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                     },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(function(response){
            if (!response.ok)
                throw new Error("Não foi possível completar o cadastro")
            return response.json() 
        })
        .then(function(data){ 
            alert("Usuário cadastrado com sucesso" + data)
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            alert(error.message);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the error message ?

Comment: You need to check the server script to see why it's returning error 409.

Comment: This is what I have on console ```POST https://api-ucdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/ 409
submitRegister @ index.js:14
onsubmit @ index.html:83
index.js:33 There has been a problem with your fetch operation: Não foi possível completar o cadastro``` I don't have access to the backend logs, but another user that's coding on it too said that works properly